# changing a while loop into a for loop in ANSI c80

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to change this into a for loop but im not sure how to.

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    tweet[cnt] = c;
    ++cnt;
}
```

Comment: I'm just not sure on how to fin the (c = getchar()) != EOF into the for loop.

Comment: Why do you want to change this into a for loop? It's fine as it is.

Comment: Is this homework? It seems like answering it would negate the whole point of trying to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Its not homework I am just trying to figure out the differences between doing one over the other. I'm making an annonymizer the blocks out emails and usernames.

Comment: I sincerely hope they don't teach this as homework.

Comment: When asking a homework question, please refer to [these guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/174714). Most importantly, **what have you tried?**

Comment: Its not homework lol and i see what i did wrong now i left the cnt++ inside the body of the for-loop and didnt realize that i could just put the body of the while into the middle of the for-loop :/ this is my third week learning C and im just doing examples from the book.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(cnt = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; cnt++)
{
    tweet[cnt] = c;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Raja :) this actually helped me out a ton!

Answer (score 1):

While loops and for loops are not so different. The while loop contains only an comparison, if its true it is executed once more until the comparison is made and it not true any more.

The for statement is the same only contains 3 parts separated by ';'.
the first is the part you want to do one time before entering the ever ending cycle.
The second part is the same as the while loop.
The third part is what you want to do after one cycle is done before getting to the next comparison for entering again.

Lot of compilers accept more than one statement in the first and last part. In this case you could get this:

```
for(cnt=0; , x=0 ; (c=getchar()) != EOF; CNT++, x++){
    tweet[cnt] = c;
}
int TheNumberOfCyclesMade = x;
```